# Append to a list in python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am tring to populate both matrix_of_ones and inner_matrix inside a for loop but the final matrix is not what i expect. I expect matrix_of_ones  to be equal expected_for_loop_output after the for loop is finished executing but the for loop actually generates actual_for_loop_output below. Could someone please why this is so?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpw3h.png)

I expect matrix_of_ones  to be equal expected_for_loop_output after the for loop is finished executing but the for loop actually generates actual_for_loop_output.

Comment: Don't post images of code.  Post the code.

Comment: You keep appending the same list after making changes to it, so you end up with 3 copies of the final version.

Comment: See the duplicate answer.  When you have multiple references to the same list, changing one of those lists changes them all (since there's only one).

Comment: Next time, try to run in the visual platform to see what's happening each step - https://pythontutor.com/